# Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following if condition is causing an error:

```
if( !empty ($this -> session -> userdata( 'user_id') ) )
{
    $user_id = $this -> session -> userdata( 'user_id' );
} 
else 
{ 
    $error = "ID doesn't exist";
}
```

I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in (line number)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where does the `(line number)` point to?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Replace the first `if` statement with `if( ! $this->session->userdata('user_id') )`.

The [`empty`](https://www.php.net/empty) function check if a variable is empty but `userdata` is a function. Additionally, for your information, according to the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), the `userdata` function returns `FALSE` if the item doesn't exist, which means that if `user_id` doesn't exist in your session, the code in the `else` will be executed.

Comment: Thank you. The error is so vague, I wasn't sure what it was referring to.

Comment: Beautiful justification - "userdata is a function". That's the kind of explanation a starter needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the sessions library of codeigniter then you don't need to check your data 
 codeigniter already does that for you.
 if `$this -> session -> userdata( 'user_id')` is empty or not set then it will be returned as false. So just a code something like that

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
if(!$user_id){  }else{ $error = 'ID doesn't exist'; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Function empty() cannot be used in this way. It expects reference argument, but not a direct function return. A function return is not considered a variable, which can be passed by reference.

```
$test = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

if(!empty($test))
    $user_id = $test;
else
    $error = "ID doesn't exist";
```

Answer (score 2):

> if( ($this -> session -> userdata( 'user_id') > 0)

it is more better instead of  **if( !$this -> session -> userdata( 'user_id') )**

because sometimes it will make error

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error caused due to PHP version. Latest Codeigniter version support above PHP 7.0. You just need to update PHP version from cpanel to 7.0 or above. Hope this help others those who are using latest codeigniter. I had same issue on below line.

```
    if($ci->session->userdata('front_logged_in') && !$ci->session->userdata('front_logged_in')){
```