# Codeigniter Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter Code:

```
if(is_dir('uploads/'.$data['pet'][0]['pet_hidenum'])){
    if(isset($this->input->post('lostimage1'))){
        $filedata = explode(',', $this->input->post('lostimage1'));
        $pos  = strpos($this->input->post('lostimage1'), ';');
        $type = explode(':', substr($this->input->post('lostimage1'), 0, $pos))[1];
        $type = '.'.$type;
        $type = str_replace('image/', '', $type);
        $img['img'] = $img['img'].''.$type;
        write_file('./uploads/'.$data['pet'][0]['pet_hidenum'].'/'.$img['img'], base64_decode($filedata[1]));
    }
}
```

Why is this error appearing van anyone p[lease help me how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730216/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139264/cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use method return value in write context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context)

Comment: `$exploded = explode(':', substr($this->input->post('lostimage1'), 0, $pos)); $type = $exploded[1];`

Answer (score 0):

This happen when you are using an old version of php so you can not do `explode(':', substr($this->input->post('lostimage1'), 0, $pos))[1];`

Try this:

```
if(is_dir('uploads/'.$data['pet'][0]['pet_hidenum'])){
if(isset($this->input->post('lostimage1'))){
    $filedata = explode(',', $this->input->post('lostimage1'));
    $pos  = strpos($this->input->post('lostimage1'), ';');
    $aux = substr($this->input->post('lostimage1'), 0, $pos);
    $type = explode(':', $aux)[1];
    $type = '.'.$type;
    $type = str_replace('image/', '', $type);
    $img['img'] = $img['img'].''.$type;
    write_file('./uploads/'.$data['pet'][0]['pet_hidenum'].'/'.$img['img'], base64_decode($filedata[1]));
}
}
```